# Do we use a Model.new in a Rails new method only so that we can associate the form with an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a new and create method:

```
  def new
    @post = Post.new
    puts @post
    puts @post.object_id
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    puts @post
    puts @post.object_id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

For a while I thought that the create method had some rails magic tied to it where it knew how to get the instance of a model from the new method and then create it in the DB.

Realizing that this is incorrect, then, is the reason we call Post.new in the new method so that we have access to the form helpers for the object and its attributes and can pass those into Create as parameters?

Then in create... We call `Post.new(params)`... To me in the code it doesn't look like we explicitly call .create or .save anywhere (yes I see we check for a condition that yields true or false using save). So how does creating a new instance of an object and passing it parameters save it?

I am a little lost and am looking for some clarification, confirmation, general assistance on these beginner questions.

Or maybe I should stick with golf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is the reason we call Post.new in the new method so that we have access to the form helpers

Yes, essentially. It allows you to use, for example, `form_for @post`.

> To me in the code it doesn't look like we explicitly call .create or .save anywhere (yes I see we check for a condition that yields true or false using save)

Using `if @post.save` *is* calling `@post.save`. That saves the post, and returns `true` on success and `false` on failure. Methods can *do* things and also return values, and this method persist the record and returns a boolean.

Comment: Maybe i need to go even further to the basics. I thought a conditional only checks for a condition and returns true or false. Does it also execute a method call if the condition it is checking normally performs a function?

Comment: @adamscott `@post.save` **is** a method call. It doesn't matter if it's in an `if` or not.

Answer (score 0):

When you run this line

```
@post = Post.new(post_params)
```

You are creating a new instance of `Post` with the parameters that are allowed, `post_params` is a method that is defined in the controller that permits certain attributes.

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
end
```

In this case, only `title` and `content` are permitted to be created with the post. The post will most likely also have a `created_at`, and `updated_at` attributes, but that is automatically set, so it is not an attribute that the user can edit/create. You can read more about [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters)

The `if` statement reads

```
if @post.save
```

This is basically saying if the post can be saved without error, save the post and run the code in the `if` statement.

Think of it as saying if the post was successfully saved, then do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are few thing to consider...

we are in RESTful environment.

1. Why we use Model.new
      its mainly to **get(GET REQUEST)** the empty model to provide for the user to fill in the information.So here comes the `form helpers` which is used to fill in the details in the form and fill the empty bucket for the model which is the attributes and the values provided by the users using the form.

So basically ,you are only providing an emtpy record...that can be used for the user to fill in.

1. Why do we again user Model.new(params)

So,in continuity with above explanation,once the bucket is ready from the user,we use the create action in the form to **post the data (POST REQUEST)**
.So that data,if you see your sever logs in wrapped in an parent node...like

```
Processing by PicturesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"picture"=>{"title"=>["testing"]}
```

### picture model

this data is wrapped in params which you define at the controller level since `Rails 4`,which is as easy a using it directly like `Model.new(params)` which is nothing but  `Model.new(title: "testing")` which is use to create a new object-**needed for validation/callbacks** to check whether user has provided valid details.

Hence,you check this with if/else statement which most rails create action has.

..HOPE IT HELPS